# TAPI register incoming call number - no lines available

Tags: c#, call, tapi

I'm a junior developer with a non IT background and currently stuck on a feature that I was asked to implement. Since there are barely helpful information and examples on the Internet I'm grateful for any help and input.

What I use: C# WinForms App

What to implement: A simple form that can identify an incoming call via TAPI3 and show the number

I've installed the TSP for our office phone. I've also found [this demo app](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10994/TAPI-3-0-Application-development-using-C-NET). However, it doesn't show me any available lines. A developer previously working on this feature 2 years ago told me that the code worked for him.

That made me wonder and I downloaded a test tool in order to check my TAPI setup ([Ephone](https://support.estos.de/en/procall-enterprise/analyse-nutzung-des-tapi-test-tools-ephone-exe-zur-ueberpruefung-von-tapi-leitungen-des-tsp)). I also tried Microsoft's dialer.exe. However both of them say I have no TAPI devices installed - even though the TSP is listed in the 'Phone and modem'.

I feel like I'm missing something essential here. Do I need to make further configurations or setups in order to use TAPI on my PC? Or is the demo app broken?

Answer (score 0):

Can be a bunch of things really, the most common things to check:

1. TSP installed
2. TSP added to "phone and modem" advanced tab
3. Select the TSP in the Providers list and use "Configure" button, this should pop-up some sort of UI (tends to need things filled in like the PBX ip and an account)
4. For some PBX you also need to have a license to use TAPI or license per device for TAPI
5. In the PBX itself, you often need to configure TAPI in some way, either per device or adding devices it to a group. Also may need to set permissions for the account (3) used, or need to be in the same group
6. Depending on what the TSP uses to connect with the PBX, may need to open some ports on any firewalls involved.

Sorry to be a bit vague here, but all of this is very dependent on make/model/brand of the PBX and TSP you are using, so can't give you a very targeted answer here.

Comment: Hey, thanks so far. I'll check the list with my team leader :)

Answer (score 0):

The following solution has worked for me:

1. In 'Phone and modem', set the IP as the switch name for the TSP.
2. Set the following service to automatic start: Remote Access Connection Manager and Telephony.